# Change color in contour3D

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I wrote this simple code for a 3D plot of two functions. How can I change the color of my plots?

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f1(x,y):
    return 454.586-x-y
def f2(x,y):
    return 293.53-x
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(70, 6, 300)
y = np.linspace(70, 6, 300)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f1(X, Y)
ZZ = f2(X, Y)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(X, Y, Z, 50, cmap='binary')
ax.contour3D(X, Y, ZZ, 50, cmap='binary')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the color in the argument "**cmap**" of the function **contour3D**.

For example:

```
from mpl_toolkits import mplot3d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def f1(x,y):
    return 454.586-x-y
def f2(x,y):
    return 293.53-x
import numpy as np
x = np.linspace(70, 6, 300)
y = np.linspace(70, 6, 300)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f1(X, Y)
ZZ = f2(X, Y)
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
ax.contour3D(X, Y, Z, 50, cmap='viridis')
ax.contour3D(X, Y, ZZ, 50, cmap='plasma')
ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')
ax.set_zlabel('z')
plt.show()
```

Here you have the [colors list](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html)